# ember-rails upgrading emberjs version confusing tmp folder

Tags: ember.js, ember-rails

**I am new to both rails and emberjs**
I want to try query params which is availble in newer emberjs builds.
so I did `rails generate ember:install --channel=canary` in my vendor folder is saw
updated emberjs file version `* @version   1.6.0-beta.1+canary.3bcd9bdc`
but when i do rails s -e test two files are generate in tmp>ember-rails which i assume is created so as to use in my application.js

but when I open **tmp>ember-rails>emberjs** file is see the version of emberjs to be  * @version   1.4.0
is this right or should it be 1.6.0-beta.1+canary.3bcd9bdc

**Part 2** 
To use new feature I asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21964405/43327) as per answer no matter where i move line

```
ENV = {FEATURES: {'query-params-new': true}};
```

before

```
//= require ember
```

It gives me error ember not defined.

Answer (score 1):

The way that ember-rails deals with the various variants of Ember is to store them in `tmp/ember`.  After updating with `rails g ember:install --channel=canary` you also need to `rake tmp:clear` to ensure the old files are gone.

This is a bug in the generator, and I have opened an issue [#343](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/issues/343) to fix it.

Comment: I did rake tmp:clear but it does not work neither does manually deleting the file from tmp folder helps. It still generate emberjs file with old version.

Comment: is the part two of the question related to it. I am not sure. Thanks.